# What is causing the text area to push up instead of aligning at the bottom of my menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a project I've been working on. Each time I finish it, I delete and everything and start over. The problem is, I can't seem to do it without getting stuck at least once.

Current problem: What is causing the text area to overlap the top menu instead of filling the space?

http://jsfiddle.net/1dan6dry/

```
/* --------- * --------- */

    body, html {

    }

/* --------- MENU --------- */

    #menu {
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: #EBE9EB; 
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
    }




/* --------- LOGO --------- */

    #logo {
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold; 
        margin-left: 15px; 
        font-size: 20px; 
        height: 20px;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000; 
        color: #9d9d9a;
        position: relative; 
        top: 12px; 
    }

/* --------- BUTTON --------- */

    #button {
        float: right;
        width: 50px;
        height: 30;
        background-color: #7E7E7E; 
        position: relative;
        top: 12px;
        right: 15px;  
        font-family: helvetica; 

    }



/* --------- TOGGLE --------- */

    .toggle {
        height: 35px;
        width: 348.9px;
        list-style: none; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-family: helvetica; 
        position: relative; 
        margin: 0 auto; 
        top: 7px; 
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 5px; 
        line-height: 35px; 
    }

/* --------- LI --------- */

    .toggle li {
        float: left; 
        padding-left: 30px; 
        padding-right: 30px; 
        text-align: center; 
        line-height: 35px; 
        border-right: 1px solid black;


    }

    #resultLi {
        border-right: none;

    }

    #htmlLi {
        margin-left: -40px; 

    }

/* --------- SELECTED --------- */

    .selected {
        background-color: #7E7E7E; 

    }

/* --------- CONTAINERS --------- */

    #CSSContainer, #JSContainer {
        display: none;
    }

    .codeContainer {
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
        padding: 0; 
        margin: 0; 
        float: left; 
        position: relative;


    }

    .codeContainer textarea {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%; 
        position: relative; 
    }



</style>
```

```
 <div id="menu">

    <div id="logo">Codeplayer</div>

    <button id="button">Run</button>

    <ul class="toggle">
        <li id="htmlLi" class="selected">HTML</li>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>JS</li>
        <li id="resultLi" class="selected">Result</li>

    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>


    <div class="codeContainer" id="HTMLContainer">
        <textarea>HTML Container</textarea>
    </div>
 <!-- 
    <div class="codeContainer" id="CSSContainer">
        <textarea>HTML Container</textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="codeContainer" id="JSContainer">
        <textarea>HTML Container</textarea>
    </div> -->

<!--         <iframe>Result</iframe>
-->



</div>


<script>

    var windowHeight = $(window).height(); 
    var menuHeight = $("#menu").height(); 
    var containerHeight = windowHeight-menuHeight; 
    $(".codeContainer").height(containerHeight+"px"); 


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the css in .codeContainer to display block.

it is overlapping because it is floated and taken out of the normal flow of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed height on the menu div, the textarea container is floated and you have moved the toggle div down.

Remove the height from #menu, use a padding on #menu instead of relative positioning on .toggle, remove the float from .codeContainer.

That should get you what you want

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/utsavoza/o1yer0vm/

add one property in your class codeContainer

```
padding-top:14px;
```